# Macro to copy sheets into workbook stops after one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook where to speed computation (long story) I created a macro to copy out three of the sheets to another file and then another macro to copy them back it.

The macro to copy out works fine, however the macro to copy back in halts after copying in one sheet.

I searched within StackOverflow and found some similar questions but couldn't find an answer which worked. One post thought it was related to Office versions and one to a Shift key issue.

Here is the code:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = False

'
'   Set up the  workbooks
'
Set ThisWkb = ThisWorkbook
Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    fileFilter:="Excel Macro Files, *.xlsm", _
    Title:="Select the Storage File", _
    MultiSelect:=False)
Set StorageWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)
'   
 MsgBox ("Beginning process - please click ok to any macro warning - you will see a confirmation when complete")


StorageWbk.Sheets("Sh A").Copy After:=ThisWkb.Sheets(ThisWkb.Sheets.Count)
StorageWbk.Sheets("Sh B").Copy After:=ThisWkb.Sheets(ThisWkb.Sheets.Count)
StorageWbk.Sheets("Sh C").Copy After:=ThisWkb.Sheets(ThisWkb.Sheets.Count)

StorageWbk.Close
```

I sometimes find that if I then delete the new sheet and run the macro again it sometimes works and reads all three sheets in, but it also sometimes doesn't.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The macro just stops after one sheet, or do you get an error?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the question. The macro just stops with no error.

Comment: What happens if you copy all three sheets at once - `StorageWbk.Sheets(Array("Sh A", "Sh B", "Sh C")).Copy After:=ThisWkb.Sheets(ThisWkb.Sheets.Count)`?

Comment: Are there any hidden sheets in your Workbook? Also can you just set the sheet index to copy after to 1 just to test?

Comment: Thanks to both YowE3K and nbayly. YowE3K's code made the macro complete successfully, and while setting the copy after to 1 didn't work nbayly's question re the hidden sheet was on the mark. Unhiding the sheet led the original code to successfully complete!

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting both YowE3K and nbayly to give the correct answer from the comments directly here (I had to look for it):

Unhide your hidden Sheets and copy the three links at once using:

```
StorageWbk.Sheets(Array("Sh A", "Sh B", "Sh C")).Copy After:=ThisWkb.Sheets(ThisWkb.Sheets.Count)
```